# Retrieve node element's value based on attribute

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

How to retrieve node element's value based on attribute name using dom & xml parsing

```
<ROOT>
    <A>
        <aa name="xyz">k,l,m </aa>
        <aa name="pqr">a,b,h </aa>
        <aa name="abc">s,t,r </aa>
         ...
    </A>
    <B>
        <bb name="t1">r,st,t</bb>
        ...
    </B>
</ROOT>
```

...
Fragment of implementation tried:

```
NodeList nodeList = <xmlDoc>.getElementsByTagName("aa");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++)
        {
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);

            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
            {
                Element element = (Element) node;

                System.out.println(element.getTextContent());
```

// ? getNodeValue() // ? how to get by passing attribute name as matching criteria,

// f.e :  how to get `a,b,h` printed for node `aa` with attribute name as `pqr`

Answer (score 0):

For attribute it will be : `element.getAttribute("name");`

If you want to search by attribute, then

```
            XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            NodeList nl = (NodeList)xpath.compile("//aa[@name='pqr']").evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

//Rest of the code same
```

*Please change the xpath according to your need. I did not run it myself, but you get the idea.